Scaffold command works in one Blazor project but not Another
I run the following command in one Project and it succeeds but in another Project it Fails.  I don't understand why because both Projects have the identical packages installed.
Thank you
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-5RF3VL6;Initial Catalog=OHR;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables dbo.tblGenerators -Force



Both Projects have the same Packages installed.
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>

